# Python DateTime does not match format when use the function inside celery task

Tags: python, redis, celery, datetime-format

I create a function to get the different between two date time and its working fine, But when i use it in celery it returns the following error:

**ValueError: time data '2023-02-16T14:38:33.301574' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'**

Any advice please

Comment: What does this have to do with *celery*. It is clear that the string contains data that does not match the specified format. You need to account for **T**

Comment: Do you have the relevant part of your code? Since you're using Python's DateTime, couldn't you just use `strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")`?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not doing this. Python standard library gives you everything you need to deal with ISO 8601 formatted date/time data. I advise you to use [datetime.datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) and [datetime.datetime.isoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) instead.